# Angular is undefined (only on server IIS but not on local IIS Express)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC app that has a small test written in angular.js.  The MVC code and the angular script worked fine in IIS Express in my development workstation.  I published the app to a server's IIS.  The MVC code worked but when I opened the view (edit.cshtml) that has the test angular script, it said "angular is undefined" in the 1st line of UFSR.js.  Thank you.

Here are my _layout.cshtml, UFSR.js, and edit.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @RenderSection("Styles", required: false) @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    ......
  </header>
  <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <div>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - An ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") 
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") 
  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

```js
var ufsrApp = angular.module('ufsrApp', [])

ufsrApp.controller('ufsrController', function($scope) {

  $scope.countries = {
    'usa': {
      'San Francisco': ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'],
      'Los Angeles': ['Burbank', 'Hollywood']
    },
    'canada': {
      'People dont live here': ['igloo', 'cave']
    }
  };
});
```

```html
@model nwicModel.dtoUserProfile
<br />
<div ng-app="ufsrApp">
  <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

  <div ng-controller="ufsrController">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        @* script omitted *@
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          Country:
          <select id="country" ng-model="cities" ng-options="country for (country, cities) in countries">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>
          City:
          <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="suburbs" ng-options="city for (city, suburbs) in cities">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>
          Suburb:
          <select id="suburb" ng-disabled="!suburbs" ng-model="suburb" ng-options="suburb for suburb in suburbs">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" ng-model="test" />{{test}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@section Scripts { 
  @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@ 
  @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")*@
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/UFSR.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: On your browser console/network, are you sure that the angular js file is been downloaded ? And the path it's rigth ?

Comment: yes, all files are downloaded with Result 200 and I can see them in the IE Developer (F12) network tab.

Comment: What happens if you use script.render instead of the script ref ? It's still remains the problem ?

Comment: I did the @Scripts.Render with the .js in the bundle that I now commented out because it didn't work on the server.

Comment: So any changes ? If your scripts.render it's not working on your server, are you sure that the server has the framework installed ? Because it should be working normal on both environments, besides that the bundles are better

Comment: The server has .Net Framework 4.5.1 installed.  The Scripts directory has all the .js required by this app.  The deployment folder in the IIS is configured correctly because I deployed another working angular app there before.  I am going to publish that app again to see if it still runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my Internet Explorer is default to IE7 mode instead of newer mode.  When I change to Edge or 10, then my app works.